# Exporting tables to csv- separating tables in a list- shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny, export-to-csv

I have a list of tables (df_list). I want to export them to csv in shiny. When exporting the list of tables to csv I open them in excel. In excel the list of tables are put into columns and the columns referred to by tablename.colname. I would like to have the tables headed by the tble name with separate col names as the following shows.

```
 Cy3 control
          Cy5     Cy3    Cy5   Cy3
    Min.    0   14170   6043    15
    1st Qu. 1   14710   6329    16
    Median  1   14960   6833    16
    Mean    3.2 15190   6679    16.47
    3rd Qu. 4.5 15830   7008    17
    Max.    15  16070   7309    19

    Cy3.control.Cy5 Cy3.control.Cy3 Cy5.control.Cy5 Cy5.control.Cy3
Min.              0             170        6043              15
1st Qu.           1           14710        6329              16
Median            1           14960        6833              16
Mean            3.2           15190        6679           16.47
3rd Qu.         4.5           15830        7008              17
Max.             15           16070        7309              19
```

Is it possible to also add a cell above which gives information about the table for example- Name of experiment etc.. which does not interact with the other cells.

The code i am using to generate the files is as follows:

```
UI.R:

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
             fileInput("rawdata", "Enter your .csv file"),
             br,
             textInput('table_name', 'Data table name to save'),
             downloadButton('downloadtable', 'Save data table to .csv')
             ),

  ) #end fluidrow
 )  ### Fluid page end 
)    #### Shiny UI end

Server:


  #### Initiate shinyServer
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    ### This reactive function will take the input "inFile" from the UI.R and store it as data
    inFile<-reactive({
      file1<-input$rawdata
      if(is.null(file1)) stop ("Please Upload a Valid .csv file")
      datas<-fread(file1$datapath,)


      dtableInput<- reactive({
        if(is.null(inFile())) 
          return()

        datas<-inFile()        

        ## apply the following functions over the list

        df_list<-lapply(df_list,function(x){

          ## store the summaries of the Cy5 and Cy3 by block

          Cy5<-summary(x$y1)

          Cy3<-summary(x$y2)

          cbind(y1,y2)    

        })


      })

      output$downloadtable<-downloadHandler(                             #### called from UI
        filename = function() {paste(input$table_name, '.csv', sep='')},
        content = function (file){
          write.csv(dtableInput(),file)
        })

    }) ## end of app
```

Comment: Kind of hard to answer with just that piece of code. I will note a few things: 

- 1. You are just defining a function to write a csv, not actually calling it anywhere that I could see. So nothing will happen.
-  2. Try writing a very small example that just writes a toy csv in a tiny shiny program and post that. Then we can help much better.

Comment: Yes you are right the code does not make sense I have edited to a working example. Thanks Mike

Comment: Okay, let me have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, took awhile because I had never worked with `fileInput` and `downLoad` buttons from Shiny before. Basically what I post below is probably close to what you wanted. It allows you to select a file to upload, and then choose a place to download it.

I didn't build your summary tables, I think you can handle that on your own and it confuses the file handling issues.

One caveat is that it does not work in the normal RStudio viewer (maybe a bug? it does not save the file), you have to use the browser (click the dropdown next to the Run App button and select `Run External` (see the screenshot below)

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
     column(4,
            fileInput("rawdata", "Enter your .csv file"),
            br(),
            textInput('table_name', 'Data table name to save'),
            downloadButton('downloadtable', 'Save data table to .csv')
      )

  ) #end fluidrow
)  ### Fluid page end 
)    #### Shiny UI end
```

server.R:

```
#### Initiate shinyServer
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  inFile<-reactive({
    file1<-input$rawdata
    if(is.null(file1)) stop ("Please Upload a Valid .csv file")
    datas<-read.csv(file=file1$datapath)
  })

  dtableInput<- reactive({
    if(is.null(inFile())) 
      return()
    datas<-inFile()        
  })

    output$downloadtable<-downloadHandler(        #### called from UI
      filename = function() {paste(input$table_name, '.csv', sep='')},
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(dtableInput(), file)
      }
    )
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark
Yes this does work for upload files. It is the downloading I'm am concerned with. For example a download version of file.choose(). Other than read.csv in your code which is replaced by fread in mine, I can't see the immediate functional difference. Any thoughts? Oh yes I should have said, the bug relating to the 'run external' is a pain....

Comment: Well, it works for one thing. I had to rearrange your code a lot to fix that. You had a lot of things nested and it wouldn't compile. ui.R wouldn't compile either.
This does both an upload and a download, so I don't know what you are asking for.

Comment: Yep thanks Mike. I have realised the issue. Yes it does work externally. I am running mine through a browser in which it is having trouble. This is chrome's problem now. Thanks for the help.